# Determine what is the best order for running filters on a dataset

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to figure out what is the optimal order for running a sequence of tasks in a pipeline.

Each task filters a percentage of the dataset.

Assuming I got the tasks *t1, t2, t3, ..., ti* and a dataset. Each task have an execution time per item in the dataset denoted as *e1, e2, e3, ..., ei* and each task filters a certain percentage of the dataset denoted as *f1, f2, f3, ..., fi*.

What is the optimal sequence of tasks to achieve the minimum running time ?

I've first tried to examine two tasks - *t1* and *t2* with their representative execution time and filter percentage - *e1, f1* and *e2, f2*.

I want to find the ordering predicate for getting e1 + f1*e2 < e2 + f2*e1. I'll get the condition *e1 / (1 - f1) < e2 / (1 - f2)*. And I guess that from here I'll need to prove it in induction, but I'm stuck because the equation is some kind of recursion.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you do your own homework.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thanks for your comment. I tried to add some more information. Actually it's not homework, but a try to improve a pipeline at work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove that the optimal ordering is according to ascending order of `e(i)/f(i)`.

**Proof:**

Let `r(i) = 1 - f(i)`.
The total cost of an ordering is: `e(1) + e(2)*r(1) + e(3)*r(2)*r(1) + ... + e(N)*r(N-1)*...*r(1)`

Now, assume that there's an optimal ordering that *doesn't* follow the rule above. It follows that there are two adjacent tasks t(i) and t(i+1) such that `e(i)/(1-r(i)) > e(i+1)/(1-r(i+1)) => e(i)*(1-r(i+1)) > e(i+1)*(1-r(i))`
swapping these two will change the value of only two expressions in the total cost expression, resulting in a delta of:

```
e(i) * r(i-1)*...*r(1) + e(i+1)*r(i)*...*r(1) -
[e(i+1)*r(i-1)*...*r(1) + e(i)*r(i+1)*r(i-1)*...*r(1)] =
r(i-1)*...*r(1)*[e(i) + e(i+1)*r(i) - e(i+1) - e(i)*r(i+1)] =
r(i-1)*...*r(1)*[e(i)*(1-r(i+1)) - e(i+1)*(1-r(i))] > 0
```

The delta is positive, meaning that the original configuration is more expensive than the outcome of the swap, therefore we have a contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.